# Custom Template is not getting loaded after new stencil CLI update on 18th Jan , 2017

Tags: command-line-interface, bigcommerce, cornerstone

We have a store , built on stencil theme Cornerstone Light . We have implemented some custom templates. Which were working fine. After some update made by bigcommerce in stencil, The custom templates is not getting loaded and the following error is coming :
**

> Uncaught Error: pages/custom/product/[custom_template] Module not
>   found

**

Can any one please help us regarding this issue?

Comment: Please do some effort before submit your question....

Comment: Can you help us on this? We are not finding any thing on net. we have updated stencil cli as mentioned in Bigcommerce doc , that it will automatically install the corrections. But no luck. Issue persists.

Comment: Do you have it mapped out in your `.stencil` file?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/release-notes